# Make buildroot use prebuild binaries

Tags: buildroot

Is it possible to cause buildroot to use a prebuild binary for packages?

For example, if, for a certain version, it determines a binary package exists, it would simply download it and would not recompile the package, even on a clean build?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not directly possible in Buildroot. There are a lot of other details that you need to take into consideration besides just the version number to know if a prebuilt binary would be compatible (E.G. architecture/variant/fpu settings/toolchain/what patches are applied/optional dependencies and so on), but for a very specific setup you might get away with creating a tarball of output/build/-version and extracting this before building.

But beware, as explained above it is quite fragile.

Comment: All those things can and should be kept in the built artifact metadata. This is hardly an excuse for not reusing a prebuilt binary.
For a team that works on a project, it doesn't make sense to keep recompiling Qt every clean build....

Comment: Well, all I'm saying is that this isn't supported in Buildroot. I agree that if you would want to do something like that, you would need to track all this meta data. Clean builds are normally only used for integration tests, so a typical use case is that you build a sdk for your team for their day-to-day work and have jenkins/buildbot/whatever do clean builds for integration testing